# How to use int value in define function

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In my program I've a lot of variables which names consist of: word+number.
For example if I `rand()` number 6 - I have to iterate word6.
I tried to make a define function to make it easier for me, but I don't know how to parse the value of an argument.

```
#define it(c,t) c ## t

*in main:*
int c1=0 ,t=1;
it(c , t)++;
cout<<c1;
```

Can you tell me how to make it work please?

Comment: Do not do it, avoid code obfuscation.

Comment: In short, this is not how the pre-processor works. All the values need to be known ahead of time, otherwise known as `const`. It seems more like you maybe just want an array?

Comment: Sounds like you want an array instead.

Comment: Of course array is a solution, I'm just wondering if there is any other :)

Comment: @Adrian What is your actual use case for such macro definition? Sounds like a XY-problem is asked. You should be aware that the peprocessor only does text replacement, and you end up with `ct++;`and not `c1++;`.

Comment: @Adrian, why `std::array`, of course! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this.  Consider using an array:

```
int word[6];  // Declares 6 int variables
word[0] = 1;  // Access them with an index, 0 is the first one
word[5] = 42; // Access the last one.
```

This uses less characters and is how others will expect you to do this.  This is probably what you want.